# Get In That DB! Parsing CSV Using Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, fastercsv

I have a CSV file formatted just like this:

```
name,color,tasty,qty
apple,red,true,3
orange,orange,false,4
pear,greenish-yellowish,true,1
```

As you can see, each column in the Ruby OO world represents a mix of types -- string, string, boolean, int.

Now, ultimately, I want to parse each line in the file, determine the appropriate type, and insert that row into a database via a Rails migration.  For ex:

```
Fruit.create(:name => 'apple', :color => 'red', :tasty => true, :qty => 3)
```

Help!

Comment: What was the standard 7 years ago?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Ruby 1.8:

```
require 'fastercsv'

FasterCSV.parse(my_string, :headers => true) do |row|
  Fruit.create!(
    :name => row['name'],
    :color => row['color'],
    :tasty => row['tasty'] == 'true',
    :qty => row['qty].to_i
  )
end
```

For Ruby 1.9, just rename `FasterCSV` to `CSV` and `fastercsv` to `csv`:

```
require 'csv'

CSV.parse(my_string, :headers => true) do |row|
  # same as ruby-1.8
end
```

Comment: FasterCVS is a gem so you may have to install and don't forget to `require 'fastercvs'`

Comment: I'm getting this error: 

"Please switch to Ruby 1.9's standard CSV library.  It's FasterCSV plus support for Ruby 1.9's m17n encoding engine."

Any idea how to handle?

Comment: FasterCSV is now part of Ruby as its default CSV class so just use `require 'csv'` and you'll be good to go.